# How many different variations/editions of Monopoly are there?

Tags: monopoly, history, edition-comparison

Is there a website that has a comprehensive list of all the various editions of the Monopoly board-game there are? I'm sure there's hundreds... but I'm not having much luck finding it online.

Comment: Board Game Geeks lists [155 versions](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1406/monopoly/versions) of vanilla Monopoly (reprints, localizations) and about [1000 games](https://boardgamegeek.com/search/boardgame/page/1?q=monopoly&B1=Go) with "Monopoly" in the title (Betty Boop Monopoly, 65th anniversary edition Monopoly, anti-Monopoly, etc.)

Comment: @jejorda2: and the first localization I checked (of my hometown Arnhem, the Netherlands) isn't in the list. So that number may be quite a significant underestimate.

Comment: Monopoly.wiki.com lists over 600 editions (http://monopoly.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Monopoly_Editions)

Comment: Do different languages count?

Answer (score 6):

It depends on how you define "variations" of the game. At this moment [the monopoly wiki](http://monopoly.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Monopoly_Games_(Board)) has 1144 versions of the game, but it includes fictional editions (Monopoly Capitol City Edition from the Simpsons), predecessors (The Landlord's Game), and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Since you can [make-your-own-opoly](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00000K2IO), there are effectively infinite Monopoly variations.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you look at my website www.worldofmonopoly.com, you can exclusively see the number held by the world record holder which is 2249 different editions.
I also exclusively keep his list up to date and can say that at this point (14th August 2019) he is at 2586 now!
The list is continually updated on the website
Hope this helps.

Comment: what do you mean by the number held by the world record holder?

Comment: This is certainly an impressive website; I think J. Matthew Horton is referring to the amount of editions of monopoly a person owns.

Comment: Currently the world record holder has officially 2249 different offiicial editions and snce then he has approximately added another 1000 to the list. I have this list and a photo of every version and they are all different. We do know of more others and of course all the new ones coming in month after month after month.
There are over 1600 "modern" editions on my website and there are lots of old versions in the old "Albert" website I took over.